# VBA: Adding a condition to an ElseIf loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'd like to add one more condition to this Loop that would put "Discrepancy" into column J if there is a value in column F that is neither 0 or #VALUE.  Any and all suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you, the current code is below:

```
Sub ERS_Vlookup()

Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim h As Long

For h = 5 To Lastrow
        If IsError(ActiveSheet.Range("H" & h).Value) Or 
        IsError(ActiveSheet.Range("F" & h).Value) Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("J" & h).Value = " "
        ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("H" & h).Value <> " " And _
               ActiveSheet.Range("F" & h).Value = 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("J" & h).Value = "Paid"
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Range("J" & h).Value = "Processed Not Yet Paid"
        End If
    Next h
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the face of it, this should work, but I think you need to think it through and check whether these conditions are all mutually exclusive.

```
Sub ERS_Vlookup()

Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim h As Long

For h = 5 To Lastrow
    If IsError(Range("H" & h).Value) Or IsError(Range("F" & h).Value) Then
        Range("J" & h).Value = vbNullString
    ElseIf Range("H" & h).Value <> vbNullString And Range("F" & h).Value = 0 Then
        Range("J" & h).Value = "Paid"
    ElseIf Not IsError(Range("F" & h).Value) And Range("F" & h).Value <> 0 Then
        Range("J" & h).Value = "Discrepancy"
    Else
        Range("J" & h).Value = "Processed Not Yet Paid"
    End If
Next h

End Sub
```

Comment: Looking at your code again... You already have the oposite of that, I think I'm confused as your code has `If Not IsError(Range("F" & h).Value) And Range("F" & h).Value <> 0 Then
        Range("J" & h).Value = "Discrepancy"
    Else
        Range("J" & h).Value = "Processed Not Yet Paid"
    End If`

Comment: @Maldred - hm not sure I follow. The OP asked for "F that is neither 0 or #VALUE" which I think is what I have. I think the series of conditions does't seem very systematic.Or I may have got the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: Meant to comment on OP, thought I was reading OP my apologies

Comment: Thank You SJR.  I added the ElseIf Not statement to my code exactly as you had it and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can the use the `And` function to add booleans to loops
i recomend you visit this website http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html
for more information